# What determines UMASK for Oracle Job using UTL_FILE?

Tags: permissions, umask, oracle

A PL/SQL job **foobar622** writes files to UNIX/LINUX server using the following Oracle file I/O commands:

`UTL_FILE.FILE_OPEN`

`UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE`

`UTL_FILE.FILE_CLOSE`

In the past the files had these permissions:

```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 User_foobar_101 UnixGroup_101 563343 Apr 25 00:22 foobar622_fz.sql
  -rw-r--r-- 1 User_foobar_101 UnixGroup_101 563343 Apr 25 00:22 foobar622_fa.sql
  -rw-r--r-- 1 User_foobar_101 UnixGroup_101 563343 Apr 25 00:22 foobar622_fb.sql
  -rw-r--r-- 1 User_foobar_101 UnixGroup_101 563343 Apr 25 00:22 foobar622_fc.sql
  -rw-r--r-- 1 User_foobar_101 UnixGroup_101 563343 Apr 25 00:22 foobar622_fd.sql
```

Now **foobar622** writes with these permissions:
And I get a `permission denied` error when I try to open file in my editor.

```
  -rw-r----- 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  563343 May 22 00:22 foobar622_fa.sql
  -rw-r----- 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  563347 May 25 00:22 foobar622_fb.sql
  -rw-r----- 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  563333 May 25 00:22 foobar622_fc.sql
  -rw-r----- 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  563923 May 25 00:22 foobar622_fd.sql
```

How do I go about restoring first default permissions? Is this an Oracle setting or a UMASK setting, or what?

Answer (score 1):

You have these options.

- Add oracle user into 3rd "shared" os group, restart the database and add s bit on directory. `chgrp shared /path/utl_directory; chmod g+s /path/utl_directory;`. So files in this directory inherit gid from parent directory and your user will be able to read them
- Use ACL on directory, to your user can read these files, regardless of standard Posix posix settings
- Use Oracle parameter _trace_files_public, this might change umask internally for Oracle processes. Initially this parameter is intended for log files.